# Do WriteXml for a dataset or datatable use memory?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a datatable that contains over 10 000 rows.

When, I do :

```
Dim oTable As New System.Data.DataTable
' .....
' Filling the DataTable
' .....
oTable.writeXml("MyFile.xml")
```

Do the ***writexml()*** uses memory or HardDrive ?

I tested, and I find out that it uses a lot of memory.

Writing a file normally uses FileStreams. So it should not uses memory.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory?  Chances are that you are seeing the buffers that are being written to disk go unreleased before the next GC.

Comment: I opened the windows Task Manager, while debbuging. I can see that the usage of the memory increases by 500 MB, when I step in the writexml().

Comment: Task Manager does not measure memory consumption, it measures [working set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc441804(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ok i do agree but when I do oTable.Reset() and then GC.Collect(), the memory drops by 2 GB. I also wants to know if in the implementation to determine if it uses memory or HardDrive.

Comment: You are measuring the wrong thing. Again, that's _working set_, not _memory_. It's _virtual memory_.

Comment: Ok, i get it. Then, does it uses virtual memory? In other words, Does the application allocate a lot of memory when the function is called ? Because I have an exception out of memory.

Comment: @casperOne Task Manager since Vista shows private working set by default, not the working set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think WriteXML eating memory is normal. Just tested with 287,120 rows in a table (exported XML is nearly 200MB in size) - memory usage stayed the same. It took around 1.2GB to load this table into memory, and then open it in the editor. After running WriteXML memory consumption stayed the same during those 4-5 seconds, maybe going up and down by 1MB.

How are you filling the DataTable? If you are using some lazy loading techniques, that may explain high memory usage, but that would be not by WriteXML, and rather by the data itself.

Comment: In fact, I finished this project. I was testing it on over 2 000 000 rows with 100 columns and running with a 3gb memory computer. That's why it crashed. But as you said, it took me about 200mg.

Comment: @billybob: If you can have 2M rows, you are not supposed to be using DataTable at all, and switch to DataReader instead. It would multiply overall performance by so many times. DataTable becomes _very_ slow on big tables, according to my experience.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know at all that I can use DataReader.